# What exactly does || mean?

Tags: php, logical-operators

```
return (empty($neededRole) || strcasecmp($role, 'admin') == 0 || strcasecmp($role, $neededRole) == 0);
```

What exactly does the || mean in this statement? Can someone put this in english for me.

I promise I've googled this but I guess I don't know what to google for because I can't find anything.

thanks:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662242/can-someone-please-put-this-in-english-for-me-php-cakephp

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: -1 You should really review some programming basics. You won't code anything good in PHP if you even ignore the **very** basics of programming :(
I'm very sorry to tell you this.

Answer (score 4):

It is the OR logicial operator.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 3):

Googling symbols is always hard. Don't worry: `||` means `or` in the statement. Don't confuse it for `Xor` which is slightly different:

- `or` or `||` is meant as `A or B or A + B`
- `xor` is meant as `A or B, not both`

References:

- [Logical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is an OR operator. It is true if any of it's 'parameters' is true.

Comment: Hummm... now I'm even more confused. I thought it would at least return a value, ie admin or user. If I give you the full function would you look at it and tell me what exactly it would return? I'll stick it in the next comment

Comment: public function isAuthorized() {
  $role = $this->Auth->user('role');
  $neededRole = null;
  $prefix = !empty($this->params['prefix']) ? $this->params['prefix'] : null;
  if (!empty($prefix) && in_array($prefix, Configure::read('Routing.prefixes'))) {
   $neededRole = $prefix; 
  }
  return (empty($neededRole) || strcasecmp($role, 'admin') == 0 || strcasecmp($role, $neededRole) == 0);
 }

Comment: Do I look like a parser? Would you at least format your code?

Code in your question will probably return if user is admin or user. What I meant in my answer is: if any of OR operands if true, operator returns true, false otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Dr McKay, I appreciate your help. And sorry about the code. I can't figure out how to do a carriage return without posting a whole new comment!

Answer (score 1):

`||` means or.
It's a logical or, so it's true if at least one of the terms is true, false otherwise.